# How to format datetimeshortstring format in datacolumn in datatable

Tags: vb.net

How to format shortdatestring for datacolumn in datatable. The data is there in datatable, PlannedEndDate Should be formatted to shortdatestring.

Please suggest

```
Private Function ReadSheetToDatatable(ByVal sheetName As String) As DataTable
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable(sheetName)
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("InquiryNumber", System.Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Description", System.Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TagNo", System.Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TagDescription", System.Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("MileStone", System.Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("SubMilestone", System.Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ActivityID", System.Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("PlannedStartDate", System.Type.GetType("System.String")))
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("PlannedEndDate", System.Type.GetType("System.String")))
            'dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("PlannedStartDate", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime")))
            'dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("PlannedEndDate", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime")))

            Using con As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString())
                If (Not IsNothing(con)) Then
                    Try
                        'InquiryNumber  Description TagNo   TagDescription  MileStone   SubMilestone    ActivityID  PlannedStartDate PlannedEndDate
                        Dim strSql As String = String.Format("SELECT InquiryNumber, Description, TagNo, TagDescription, MileStone, SubMilestone, ActivityID, PlannedStartDate, PlannedEndDate FROM [{0}]", sheetName)
                        'Dim strSql As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheetName)
                        Dim dataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter()
                        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(strSql, con)
                        dataAdapter.Fill(dt)

                        Return dt
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        'PRABHU 25-NOV-2012 used by another process issue fix
                        Petrofac.PTR.Framework.Exceptions.SaveDBExceptionLog(ex.Message, Err.Number, ex.StackTrace.ToString(), "ExcelService", Petrofac.PTR.Framework.SecurityManager.GetBadgeNo())
                        _statusMessage = String.Format("Reading {0} failed ...", sheetName.Replace("$", ""))
                        Return Nothing
                    Finally
                        con.Dispose()
                    End Try
                End If
            End Using
            _statusMessage = String.Format("Reading File failed ...")
            Return Nothing
        End Function
```

Comment: why are you create plannedenddate column with string data type create with date or Assign the format in query

Comment: storing `Date` data as strings is a singularly bad idea if they are ever to be used as Dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Query like this

```
SELECT InquiryNumber, Description, TagNo, TagDescription, MileStone, 
SubMilestone,ActivityID, PlannedStartDate, 
FORMAT(PlannedEndDate ,'dd/MM/yyyy')FROM [{0}]
```

Comment: I have tested it but its coming in mm/dd/yyyy format instead of dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: Any idea how can i fix this

Comment: Input of PlannedEndDate string is something like this 7/5/2014

Comment: But I want it to convert to 07/05/2014

Comment: `SELECT Format(A,'dd/MM/yyyy') from [Sheet1$]` its work fine for me

Comment: Nice but dont know why its not working on my side..Thanks for it

Comment: @user1030181 did not open a con why?