# How to convert DateTime Column to String during Runtime in DataTable

Tags: c#

Could you please suggest how to convert Date Column to ShortDateString During Runtime in this below DataTable

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This example method generates a DataTable.
    /// </summary>
    static DataTable GetTable1()
    {
        //
        // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
        //
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the Date column to

```
  table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
```

and in the Add call change the DateTime.Now to

```
  table.Rows.Add(22, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
```

But this seems to be logically incorrect. Why do you want to have a date representend internally as a string. Leave it as a Date and, when you need to display it apply the formatting rules provided by the user interface object that you want to use to display your datatable

Comment: Thanks Steve, But my data would be coming from db, how to loop through each row to fix this up?

Comment: How to handle the datarow to convert to shortdatestring when data is coming from db

Comment: As I have said I don't understand why you need to change the datatype in the DataRow. Where do you want to display that data? In a GridView? Then look at how to format date columns in a gridview. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I do not want to use data in gridview, but however i am consuming the data from datatable to bulk saving in db. So here before saving the data from datatable to db, I want to cast the each datarow to save in dd/MM/yyyy format

Comment: Then my answer is not good for you. I suggest to explain your requirements in your question and show the code that tries to write back this data to your db

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796916/how-to-format-datetimeshortstring-format-in-datacolumn-in-datatable/24797683#24797683